# Concatenating columns and not including a column when it has a null value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following table:

> ApprovalOrder EntityCode  ProjectCode
>
> 1     1415        NULL
>
> 2     1415        NULL
>
> 3     1415        NULL

And the following code:

```
    select 
        de.ApprovalOrder + de. EntityCode + isnull(de.ProjectCode, '') as 'RowID'
    from workflow.delegation_engine de
    where EntityCode = 1415 and DelegationCode = 'CAT1'
```

Which is unfortunately returning an additive result. I'm aware this is what it should do given the above however how can I make it concatenate the result of each column into one result whilst also only including de.ProjectCode when the result it not NULL (this can be characters or integer values).

For example, if I was running query just on the first row of this table I'd like the returned result to be '11415'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be explicit about what you are doing, I would cast each item to a VARCHAR() first.

```
CAST(de.ApprovalOrder AS VARCHAR(16)) + CAST(de.EntityCode AS VARHCAR(16)) + ISNULL(CAST(de.ProjectCode AS VARCHAR(16)), '')
```

If you want a hack to avoid the explicit casting, start the derivation with a string...

```
'' + de.ApprovalOrder + de.EntityCode + ISNULL(de.ProjectCode, '')
```

Comment: Love the explicit casting example - will be worth keeping note of in future.

Answer (score 4):

You are adding two integer values instead of concatenating two strings. You should first [CAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) these `INTEGER` types to a `VARCHAR` before concatenating them.

```
SELECT  CAST(de.ApprovalOrder AS VARCHAR(32)) 
        + CAST(de.EntityCode AS VARCHAR(32)) 
        + ISNULL(CAST(de.ProjectCode AS VARCHAR(32)), '') as 'RowID'
FROM    workflow.delegation_engine de
WHERE   EntityCode = 1415 
        AND DelegationCode = 'CAT1'
```

*Note that I assumed a string length of 32 wich is more than enough to hold any INTEGER conversion (10 should be enough)*

Comment: But fun, in an "I should be in bed" kind of way :)

Comment: @Dems - Looking at your time zone, I'm one hour more overdue for *bed* time :)